# how to exit ALooper_pollAll before the timeout expires

Tags: pthreads, android-ndk, blocking, looper

Within my `android_main`, I make a call to `ALooper_pollAll` with a negative timeout value so that it waits indefinitely until an event appears. However there are cases when I need to be able to manually exit this blocked state (without having to wait for an event to occur).

To try and achieve this, I have tried calling the following from a different thread, while `ALooper_pollAll` is waiting for an event:

`ALooper_wake( ALooper_forThread() )`

however this results in a segmentation fault.

Is there a way I can manually unblock `ALooper_pollAll` before the timeout expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - my approach worked afterall, I was simply getting the handle to my ALooper from the wrong thread. Thanks!

Comment: can you share snippet of the solution (with the call to ALooper_pollAll  too) ?